# MeshBasicMaterial color gradient @react-three/fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

someone knows how to assign a gradient to a MeshBasicMaterials that in my case is a Sphere?
At the moment I have an orange #ff8300 sphere that I would like to have a gradient from #ffff00 to #ff0000.

```
<mesh>
 <sphereBufferGeometry args={[0.8, 30, 30]} attach="geometry" />
 <meshBasicMaterial color={0xff8300} attach="material" />
            
</mesh>
```

Comment: With plain `three.js` you would normally create a color gradient with a raw canvas, use it to create an instance of [THREE.CanvasTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=canvas#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture) and then apply it to the `map` property of your material.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the easiest way to accomplish a gradient material with **@react-three/fiber** is using the `GradientTexture` helper component included with [@react-three/drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#gradienttexture).

Here's a simple example that's mostly straight from the docs:

```
<mesh ref={sphereRef}>
  <sphereGeometry args={[2.5, 30, 30]} attach="geometry" />
     <meshBasicMaterial>
        <GradientTexture
          stops={[0, 1]} // As many stops as you want
          colors={['aquamarine', 'hotpink']} // Colors need to match the number of stops
          size={1024} // Size is optional, default = 1024
         />
    </meshBasicMaterial>
</mesh>
```